# Performance and number of links between tables

Tags: sql, database, performance

My current schema is getting bigger and bigger, with more than 30 tables and hundreds of links between them.

In other words, every table has three or four foreign keys.

My questions is: does this high number of links has an impact on performance?

Can you give an example on why?

Comment: A resounding: it depends. You need to be more specific, or you might as well read a book or something.

Comment: Adding complexity to the schema is always going to impact performance, but it might be only on the millisecond or microsecond level depending on your actual design, query patterns, storage hardware, server hardware etc. Also, you should consider that moving to a design with less tables and less relationships might actually be worse performance for other reasons. As stated above "it depends'.

Comment: I agree with @DanMan.  It also depends on the database engine being used, and how you've chosen to create your table's primary keys.  For instance, choosing natural keys can cause index fragmentation if on inserts they're non-sequential, at least this has been my experience with SQL Server.

Comment: More details? For example imagine the use of an ORM like Hibernate where you have to load as object all the related entities... this I think can slow down the system.

Answer (score 1):

Foreign/Primary key constraints affect the performance of

- Inserts (each foreign key constraint has to check for a matching primary key)
- Updates. Updates to a column participating in a foreign or primary key constraint trigger that constraints validation logic. Update a primary key column and every foreign key constraint referencing that primary key must be validated. Update a foreign key column and it has to be validated against the primary key.

As far as `select` queries go, assuming that you (and your DBAs) indices covering the joins you're doing, it shouldn't have too much effect on things. However, *that* all depends on what the execution plan looks like. If your join can do an index seek, you're likely looking at O(log N) performance. If it has to table scan, you're looking at O(N) or potentially O(N<sup>2</sup>) performance.

And in fact, joins of narrow tables might actually speed things up. If you have a covering index (where all the columns needed are found in the index), the database engine doesn't have to retrieve the actual data pages for the table. Further, narrow tables mean more rows per data page and thus fewer I/Os to get to the data you need.

But it all depends on context: you need to analyze your queries' execution plans and see what they are actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the number of relations alone impact the performance of your quiries.Performance issues occur when you start to join tables.As stated in the following article [The myth of slow sql joins](http://java.dzone.com/articles/myth-slow-sql-join-operations),they don't seem to have a noticeable performance hit.Of course depending on the size of your dataset this can change,but maybe not so much.Besides good indexing you can consider using subqueries.For instance consider the following sql code:

> SELECT * FROM TABLE1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.FK=TABLE2.PK WHERE TABLE1.FIELD1='SOME VALUE'

instead you could use a nested query,which can be turned on a view later on,and limit the number of rows from table 2 that are being accesed:

> SELECT * FROM TABLE1 INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM TABLE2 WHERE TABLE2.SOMEFIELD='SOME_VALUE_FOR_FIELD') ON TABLE1.FK=TABLE2.PK